# JOIN two tables with multiple rows to a single row, with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join two tables into one row for each User in table 1, but there are multiple simple but dynamic fields in table 2 that should be appended.

### Given two Tables:

- User

| USER_ID | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| U1 | John |

- ExtraData

| USER_REF_ID | DYNAMIC_EXTRA_FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| U1 | IS_EMPLOYED |
| U1 | HAS_OUTSTANDING_PAYCHECK |
| U1 | LIKES_CATS |
| ... | ... |

### Expected Output:

Either:

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | IS_EMPLOYED | HAS_OUTSTANDING_PAYCHECK | LIKES_CATS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | John | true | true | true | ... |

or

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | IS_EMPLOYED | HAS_OUTSTANDING_PAYCHECK | LIKES_CATS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | John | IS_EMPLOYED | HAS_OUTSTANDING_PAYCHECK | LIKES_CATS | ... |

### The Problem

While there are a lot of solutions for fixed column names, i cannot find a solution that accepts dynamic input. In this case I do not know what fields will be in DYNAMIC_EXTRA_FIELD

Comment: "*i cannot find a solution that accepts dynamic input*" - that's because this is not possible. One of the fundamental restrictions of SQL is that the number, names and data types of all columns must be know to the engine _before_ the query is started. It's impossible to dynamically add columns to a result of a query where the columns are determined by the result itself.

Comment: Maybe aggregating into a JSON object is an alternative? https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/pivot-alternatives/

Comment: SQL has static number of result columns. Alternative solutions usually include producing a **single column** with all dynamic data you need, You could use: 1) A simple `VARCHAR` or `CLOB`, 2) An XML doc, 3) A JSON doc, etc.

Comment: Json object aggregation is a acceptable solution in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_ref_id, array_to_json(array_agg(extradata.DYNAMIC_EXTRA_FIELD)) AS extra_data
FROM extradata
GROUP BY user_ref_id) extra on extra.user_ref_id = user.user_id
```

Will produce:

| user_id | user_name | extra_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | John | ["IS_EMPLOYED","HAS_OUTSTANDING_PAYCHECK","LIKES_CATS"] |